# Pandas-Profiling.to_widgets(): Error displaying widget: model not found

Tags: widget, pandas-profiling

Error screenshot

[image]

I've been facing an **intermittent issue with pandas profiling widget** not rendering & it has been going on and off for awhile.

I've tried this in the command prompt:

```
 jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

it comes up with " - Validating: ok" but still not rendering.

A quick google search led me to a few githubs/pandas-profiling/issues sections but they were a few years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem in Kaggle, I think it is related to memory.  It happens when I repeat running my notebook a few times, without restarting the kernel.

To fix it, I just clicked Run, then Restart and Clear Outputs, and it's working again.

I have since then optimized my codes to release memory when done with them, as well as get into the habit of restarting and clearing outputs before a fresh run.

It hasn't happened on my local environment with Jupyter Notebook, probably because I have better memory locally.  But if it did happen, I guess I would select Kernel, then Restart and Clear Output.

Comment: Thanks! The intermittent portion comes into play when I restart and clear a out put as well.

Comment: yes, that happens to me too.  What i meant was restart, clear output, and start the profiling as the first step.  My pandas profiling code is in the middle of my notebook.  Before that i have a lot of other tasks that use a lot of ram.  however, now i managed to change these code so it uses less ram, and now i have no issues.  before that,  i only get the error by the way, if GPU in kaggle is on.  If off, no problem.  however, our scenario might be different.  You might also try dataprep as an alternative to pandas profiling, very fast and looks similar.  also try sweetviz.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I didn't figure out yet how to make the to_widgets method work. As a workaround you can use the `to_html` method of the profile instance and render it using the `HTML` object from IPython.display.

The following code snippet should do the trick.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
your code here ...
HTML(profile.to_html())
```